# DSN connection runs twice

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc, dsn

I have defined System DSN connection "ASPClassic" in ODBC.

After I run the following code in Classic ASP

```
Set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "DSN=ASPClassic"
```

I can see in SQL Server two logon attempts. The first one is a failed attempt for the session user, the second one is succeeded for the admin user using Windows authentication.

The same happens even when I add the admin user to the connection string:

```
conn.open "DSN=ASPClassic;uid=adminuser"
```

My AppPool is

> No Managed Code, Classic Pipeline, Identity=Network Service, Load
>   User Profile=false

.
Why does it happen?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why I've been seeing two logon attempts.
The second logon is me running the

```
exec sp_readerrorlog
```

Comment: Do you mean this is the cause of the problem?

Comment: It's the cause of me seeing two logon attempts.

Comment: @YevgeniGrinberg Please add something like "Found the solution" then, it's not really clear.